# pinterest bookmarklet doesn't work on website

Tags: bookmarklet, pinterest

A client has a oscommerce webshop with loads of interesting stuff for people to pin on pinterest, only the pin it bookmarklet won't work. I've searched everywhere on the web but couldn't find anything worthwhile about this so I'm hoping anyone here can help me.

When I click the bookmarklet nothing shows up, but when I open firebug suddenly the pinterest overlay pops up with all the images. Once everything 10 times a pinterest alert show up saying "Sorry but we can't see any big images or videos on this page". The firebug console doesn't give me anything usefull so I'm a bit out of ideas.

Comment: You would have to give an example page where this can be tested and a link to or the code for the pinterest bookmarklet. Also explain which browser/os combinations you have tested on.

Comment: I've researched this further and as far as I can see only webkit browsers have this issue. I've found the solution also and am posting it here now.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after some more poking around I found a reference to improper DOCTYPE's screwing up some bookmarklets in Chrome. I checked against some other sites and changed all the

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

into

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

And now it works!

As a side note, the bookmarklet also doesn't catch the images etc in frames, so that might screw up some sites also.

Comment: You know that `DOCTYPE` has meaning, right? If you didn't write your website as "XHTML 1.0 strict", then it isn't correct to use that doctype, and doing so might create odd and unexpected rendering results in browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on my girlfriend's Wordpress blog.

The issue was that I had images that had the names of "a", "b", "c", "d" (because I was lazy when coding some JS OnMouseOver rollovers). These names were causing the bookmarklet to not load - once I changed the object names, the bookmarklet loaded everything just fine.

Answer (score 0):

One reason it may not work is if your site is https and the bookmarklet is old.

I noticed the Pinterest bookmarklet did nothing on our site.

The Chrome Web Inspector revealed: "[blocked] The page at https://example.com/foo ran insecure content from http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?…"

The current version of the bookmarklet is fixed to work on https sites, though of course you can't rely on your visitors to be up to date.